# Setting up Capybara to have an alias for the server it boots up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

So I have some features I'm wanting to test.

For a portion of the features I'm wanting to have requests placed to a different host.

When I'm testing my code locally (outside of Capybara) I'm able to use `localhost:3000` for a portion of the requests, and `0.0.0.0:3000` for another portion of the requests.

Any thoughts on the best approach to replicating this approach with Capybara?

If I set the default host to `localhost:3000` and spin up a server myself it works. But haven't yet been able to get it to work otherwise.

FWIW I'm using poltergeist as the js driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two Capybara settings that control the app under test server it starts are `Capybara.server_host` (defaults to 127.0.0.1) and `Capybara.server_port` (default to a random free port).  One way to get what you want is to fix the port and then pick a domain that resolves everything to 127.0.0.1 for all hostnames (`.test` on your machine possibly - or add a new name to your `hosts` file that resolves to 127.0.0.1)

```
Capybara.server_port = 9999
visit('/') # will go to http://127.0.0.1:9999/
visit('http://127.0.0.1:9999')
visit('http://my_app.test:9999')
```

The other option is to set `Capybara.always_include_port = true` which will override the port for any visit call that doesn't specifically include a port with the port Capybara has run its server on (which can therefore remain a random port Capybara picks)

```
Capybara.always_include_port = true
visit('/') # http://127.0.0.1:<server_port>/
visit('http://my_app.test') # http://my_app.test:<server_port>
visit('http://google.com') # http://google.com:<server_port>
visit('http://google.com:80/') # http://google.com
```